# Parsing words and tags from HTML in Java

Tags: java, html-parsing

I need to extract all tags and words (in chronological order) from html file. Here's the example of file:
 one two thre 
What I want at the output is an array or a list which looks like this:
{"", "one", "two", "thre", ""}
I know that there are tools such as jTidy or Apache Tina, but these tools are for extracting only text (or only tags) from a document.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Use the JSoup library for this. It makes HTML parsing in Java incredibly easy.